# S3 mini won't boot up after flashing twrp custom recovery with Odin

Tags: boot, odin

After a successful root, I tried to install twrp custom recovery, so I downloaded the appropriate tar file and flashed it using Odin, but the device never entered recovery mode when I attempted to, it only showed the Samsung logo and freezed there, but it could boot up normally to the system, so I tried the adb command "reboot recovery", it rebooted and freezed at the Samsung logo again but this time it also did the same whenever I tried to boot up the system, I am sure this can be fixed but I don't know how, Please help.

Comment: You possibly flashed the wrong version of TWRP. Check the file/download it again and try flashing the correct file.

Comment: Would that get the device out of the boot loop? would it help to install cwm recovery instead?

Comment: I have 4 devices (1 S3 Mini) with TWRP and if you can't boot, then there is more than the recovery that may be broken. The recovery is independent from the OS, so it may or may not fix your issue. If you like, install CWM and flash a fresh ROM to fix your OS.

Comment: Many thanks, I have already done that, I used odin to flash the stock rom that I downloaded from sammobile.com, and it worked, but for my surprise, the device booted and nothing were lost but the root, everything was intact, sms, contacts. apps and everything!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem, I downloaded the s3 mini stock rom from sammobile.com and extracted recovey.img from it and tried to convert it to .tar format using some batch that I found on the internet then flashed it using Odin, but the problem persisted, so i decided to flash the whole rom accepting the fact that I will be losing all of my data and messages, for my surprise, the device booted and nothing were lost but the root, everything was intact, sms, contacts. apps and everything!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is trying to flash `.tar` instead of `.img`. TAR is just archive format, that actually contains the image you need to flash.